# Create instance of an unknown type and work with it

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, types

in MVC I have a controller that check roles of an authenticated user. base on the role its need to create an instance of a class. for example, if the role is "Student" I need to create an instance of a Student class. I've been trying something like this but it doesn't work :

```
private object CurrentUser;

switch(Role)
{
   case "student":
   CurrentUser = context.Students.FirstOrDefault(std => std.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
   break;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

but I can't get Student Properties is defined. for example, when I want to get `CurrentUser`, there is no such `firstname` property available! 
how can I implant `CurrentUser`?

Comment: Not sure why 4 people voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking".  He's assigning an instance of `Student` to a variable of type `object` and does not understand why the properties of `Student` are not avaialble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined CurrentUser as type `object`.  It will not have the properties of `Student` unless you cast it.

```
private object CurrentUser;
```

You can use an interface or common base class, e.g.

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
    // Add special properties for students
}

public class Professor : Person
{
    // Add special properties for professors
}
```

Then use

```
private Person CurrentUser;
```

All of the properties available to `Person` will be available on `CurrentUser`.  If you needed to access a property that is only on `Student`, you could cast like this:

```
((Student)CurrentUser).SomePropertyOfStudent
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. I'm Also using Student Class As EF first Code to use my Database. using base class doesn't effects my database?

Comment: EF code first fully supports base classes (or indeed entire class hierarchies). See http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph